# ¿como insertar una columna en una posición especifica dentro de mi dataset?

Tags: c#, asp, datagrid

Actualmente quiero poner en lugares específicos de mi dataset valores que tomare de la sesión de mi aplicación.

Código Actual:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adaptador.Fill(ds);
            CreateColumns(ds);
            ds.Tables[0].Columns[2].DefaultValue = GetSessionSchoolId();
            dtTable.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dtTable.DataBind();
```

Ya lo intente de varias formas que vi en Internet pero todas funcionan con el datagrid ya creado y quiero que sea en el dataset directamente.

Solucion fallida 1:

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[3].Value = "Some Value";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Solución Fallida 2:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Field1";
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Field1";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Field2";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Field2";
```

Ninguna de las respuestas anteriores funciona porque el dataset no tiene estas propiedades `DataPropertyName` y `Value`

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET